# Is it possible to accept/decline access to media devices getUserMedia request without mouse?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, accessibility

Is it possible to accept/decline access to media devices in `getUserMedia` request(popup) using only keyboard (without mouse)?

The browsers I'm interested in are Chrome and Firefox.

I can't find related issues or keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question, it's a question about how to use the browsers. [su] would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Barmar is correct, this is a browser specific question so it doesn't belong on Stack Overflow as such. But the answer to your question is 'yes it is possible to access a request popup via keyboard only'.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie sorry, in the future I will be more attentive. Could you tell me how can I get access to request popup?

Comment: you can tab to it after the URL bar if you are purely using a keyboard normally in Chrome, I would guess FireFox is the same. There is no way I know of to automatically assign focus to it so you have to tab through the whole page from whatever button you pressed to trigger it.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie it's not working. Anyway, thank you for your help. I'll create ticket at https://superuser.com/ =)

Answer (score 0):

After some testing the answer to this is that `getUserMedia` requests will automatically focus the pop-up box in Chrome and you can simply tab to the accept / decline buttons.

If your application is not performing this way then you have something interfering with focus within your JavaScript that needs removing.

I tested this on Chrome back to versions 60.

If for some reason you don't end up in the pop up you can shift tab to the padlock icon and press enter, that will show all options for the site that you can confirm / deny.

For Firefox you need to tab to the section before the URL containing the video icon, padlock icon etc. then press right key to select the 'video' icon and press enter, this will take you into the pop-up box.

I find it strange Firefox does not auto-focus this box, I am guessing it is a bug.